# How do I write a git hook for a fast-forward merge?

Tags: python, bash, githooks

I want to write hook to find latest pushed commit using ff merge
with following steps

1. Take the earliest commit from target branch
2. find branches which this commit belong
3. find list of commits which avaliable from parents[1] and are unvalible for branches which was found at step 2
4. parent of  the earliest commit from this list - last pushed commit

I'm using git and hooks are written with python/bash

Comment: I think you are confused; git hooks are executed by specific events, it sounds like you just want a command line tool to do these things?

Comment: Can you suggest your variant? The problem is that i'm newer in git and writing scripts, and you'r right i'm confused.I think i should use git-rev-list, but how to release it i don't know